# Run-time error '5852' when iterating over revisions

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am easily annoyed by word tracking format changes (even in text that is newly inserted in a revision), so I am using a macro to accept all format changes, once they summed up:

```
Sub AcceptAllFormatChanges()
    Dim xRev As Revision
    Dim count As Integer
    
    count = 0
    For Each xRev In ActiveDocument.Revisions
        If Not xRev Is Nothing Then
            If xRev.Type = wdRevisionProperty Then
                count = count + 1
                xRev.Accept
            End If
        End If
    Next xRev
    MsgBox ("Accepted " & count & " format changes")
End Sub
```

This works fine most of the time, but on some documents, it gives me a run-time error '5852' - Requested object is not available on the "If xRev.Type" line. I am looking for a way to check the object that is yielded by ActiveDocument.Revisions without it throwing a run-time error. Checking for Nothing is not enough. The issue also occures when removing the xRev.Accept or when looping backwards through the revisions.

---

**Update**: I tracked down the issue to a Word Bug today. If the macro strikes, I am also unable to iterate through changes in the document using the Next Change button on the review panel. Additionally, if I open the revision panel, the number of revisions jumps back and forth between two numbers. This helped me track down those ghost revisions to a few insertions which included fields (references to other sections). I am able to correct those by deleting/reinserting, so at least now I know how to fix my documents to make the macro work again. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the bug in order to actually file a bug report.

The VBA question though remains open: Is there a way for the macro to skip those ghost revisions without throwing a run-time error?

Comment: You are looping the list of revisions and in the loop you change the list by accepting revisions.  That causes this error. Instead loop in reverse to avoid the error (for i = activedocument.revisions.count to 1 step -1) note note die is the list is 0 or 1 based.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is not the issue. The code also fails, if I remove the Accept statement and looping forward works fine for other documents. I nevertheless tried looping backwards and it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WdRevisionType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrevisiontype) instead of cryptic numbers in the code for checking the `Type` property. Also you may try to check for `Nothing` before getting the `Type` property value. The following code works like a charm for me:

```
Public Sub AcceptSelection()
    
    Dim rev As Revision
    
    For Each rev In Selection.Range.Revisions
        rev.Accept
    Next rev
    
End Sub
```

And the last resort is to replace the `for each` loop with a reverse `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added Nothing check to the code but with no success. Apparently what is returned by Revisions is "something" but not a Revision. Looping backwards does also not help (see comment below OP). Regarding your other comment, you are of course right, but wdRevisionProperty is no less cryptic for format changes than 3 :-/

Comment: Try to define the `rev` as object in the code and then check the underlying type at runtime. If it is revision then you can move forward, otherwise, just skip this unknown object.

Comment: Nope. Typeof xRev is Revision passes, still fails on trying to access xRev.Type.

Comment: Is this a problem with a specific document?

Comment: It's a problem occuring on some documents, some times. Most of the times and on most documents, the macro works fine.

Comment: Try to use `on error resume next` in that case.

Comment: Using `on error resume next` causes Word to freeze indefinitely. Likewise moving the checks to a separate sub with `on error goto :label_at_end`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't EXACTLY answer your question (ie how to 'skip the ghost revisions'), rather this removes the 'ghost' (I call 'invalid') revisions by accepting (or rejecting) them which then makes all of the subsequent revisions 'available' (ie you note that you cannot click the 'Next' button to go to the next revision ... this code fixes that).

Please note that I've only ever seen the problem you describe with one document (which contains 2 'invalid' revisions that cause an error 5852 if you query any members of them) and so the code in this answer has only ever been tested on that one document ... I'd normally want to carry out much more testing than that but cannot in this case as I can't create documents with 'invalid' revisions.

The code is commented to explain what it does and how it does it so no lengthy explanation here, other than to say that it searches for the 'last okay' revision by repeatedly splitting the collection of all revisions in the document in two and testing which half contains the 'last okay' and 'first invalid' revisions. Once located, it selects the 'last okay' revision and then moves the selection to the range of the next revision (which is the 'first invalid' revision) and accepts all revisions in that range (which is just the one 'invalid' revision) ... repeats if required (ie if the document contains more than one 'invalid' revision).

A few other notes:

- The call to [IsObjectValid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.isobjectvalid) can take several seconds on a document with many revisions and it is called repeatedly ... please be patient! - for the document I noted which has 2 invalid revisions (out of 650 in total), the code takes around 45 seconds to complete on my fairly average-spec laptop
- This code uses (and moves) the selection (it must use the selection object as the revisions collection is effectively broken) ... calling code may want to store the selection before calling this function and restore it afterwards
- This code only tests and fixes invalid revision(s) in the main body of the document (not headers, footers, footnotes etc ... obviously it can be extended to cover those)
- This code 'fixes' invalid revisions by accepting them ... change `.AcceptAll` to `.RejectAll` if preferred
- The `FixInvalidRevisions` function returns the number of fixed revisions which will be zero if the document contains no invalid revisions (or no revisions at all)
- I've left in the code some `Application.StatusBar` and `Debug.Print` calls for debugging / testing purposes, please remove or adjust to suit your needs

To use the code, call `FixInvalidRevisions` passing in the relevant document.

```
Public Function FixInvalidRevisions(doc As Document) As Long
    Dim countFixed As Long, warningShown As Boolean
    Dim indexRevOK As Long, indexRevInvalid As Long, midPoint As Long
    indexRevOK = 1
    ' this outer loop runs for each invalid revision in the document
    Do While True
        ' exit if no (or no more) invalid revisions
        If doc.Revisions.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        ElseIf IsObjectValid(doc.Revisions(doc.Revisions.Count)) Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        If Not warningShown Then
            warningShown = True
            MsgBox "The main body text of '" & doc.Name & "' contains one or more invalid revisions ... fixing " & _
                    "these can take a while, please be patient ... see the status bar for progress updates", _
                    vbOKOnly + vbInformation
        End If
        indexRevInvalid = doc.Revisions.Count
        ' When there is an invalid revision in a document, all of its properties and methods are inaccessible ... as
        ' are the properties and methods of all of the revisions FOLLOWING it in the document (you will receive an
        ' error 5852 if you try to use them). Additionally, it can take a long time (several seconds) to test each
        ' revision's validity. Hence, this code doesn't just start at the beginning (or end) of the document's
        ' collection of revisions and cycle through each one in sequence, rather it tests the revision at the mid point
        ' of the collection and adjusts the lower/upper bound of revisions to be tested depending on whether the
        ' revision at the mid point is invalid or not, repeating that cycle until the invalid revision is located
        Do While True
            Dim msg As String
            msg = "Identifying invalid revision " & (countFixed + 1) & ", between " & indexRevOK & " and " & _
                    indexRevInvalid
            Application.StatusBar = msg
            Debug.Print Now, msg
            midPoint = (indexRevOK + indexRevInvalid) \ 2
            DoEvents ' prevent Word from displaying 'not responding'
            If IsObjectValid(doc.Revisions(midPoint)) Then
                indexRevOK = midPoint
            Else
                indexRevInvalid = midPoint
            End If
            ' if the difference between the 'invalid' and 'ok' revision index is 1 then we have identified an invalid
            ' revision, but (as noted above) we can't use its properties and methods ... the way around this is to
            ' select the prior revision (or the very start of the document if the invalid revision is the first
            ' revision) then move the selection to the range of the next revision (ie the invalid revision) and then
            ' accept all revisions in that range ...
            If indexRevInvalid - indexRevOK <= 1 Then
                ' ... the thing that can trip us up, though, is if there are consecutive invalid revisions which can
                ' mean that the prior revision is also invalid ... handle that scenario
                HandleConsecutiveInvalidRevisions doc, indexRevInvalid, indexRevOK
                msg = "Fixing invalid revision " & (countFixed + 1) & " at index " & indexRevInvalid
                Application.StatusBar = msg
                Debug.Print Now, msg
                If indexRevInvalid = 1 Then
                    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
                Else
                    doc.Revisions(indexRevOK).Range.Select
                End If
                Selection.NextRevision
                ' if you just want to see where the first invalid revision is in the document, uncomment the following
                ' line
                'End
                Selection.Range.Revisions.AcceptAll ' change to .RejectAll if preferred
                countFixed = countFixed + 1
                ' exit the inner loop so that we can test for another invalid revision
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Loop
    ' tidy-up and exit
    Application.StatusBar = vbNullString
    FixInvalidRevisions = countFixed
End Function


Private Sub HandleConsecutiveInvalidRevisions(doc As Document, ByRef outIndexRevInvalid As Long, _
        ByRef outIndexRevOK As Long)
    On Error Resume Next
    Do While True
        If outIndexRevInvalid = 1 Then Exit Sub
        ' if getting the start of the range for the 'ok' revision fails then it is not actually ok, rather it is the
        ' first one of (or an earlier one of) multiple consecutive invalid revisions
        Err.Clear
        If doc.Revisions(outIndexRevOK).Range.Start > 0 Then
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        outIndexRevInvalid = outIndexRevInvalid - 1
        outIndexRevOK = outIndexRevOK - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this code, next time I come across the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple code to accept all formatting changes, that started failing on a particular document, with Error 5852. Code:

```
Sub AcceptChangedFormatting()
    Dim r As Revision
    For Each r In ActiveDocument.Revisions
    
        'If IsObjectValid(r.FormatDescription) Then
        'this crashes Word
        
            StrFD = r.FormatDescription
'this results in error 5852 sometimes


            'On Error Resume Next
            'this hangs Word
            
            If Left(StrFD, 10) = "Formatted:" Then r.Accept
        'End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

When using the commented line "If IsObjectValid(r.FormatDescription) Then" Word crashes (no error, no nothing) when opening a particular document. When using "On Error resume next" Word hangs and appears to spend a lot of processor time.

The file was modified by an external user, possibly with Mac Word or some other application.

So it seems that document corruption can cause this error and IsObjectValid or On Error resume next are not workarounds.