# Highlight tracked changes: Error 5852 - Requested object not available

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to approve all 'tracked changes', and highlight what was changed. Basically, changing 'track changes' to highlights.

```vb
Sub AcceptChangesAndHighlight()
Dim rev As Revision
Dim rng As Range

For Each rev In ActiveDocument.Revisions
    Set rng = rev.Range
    rng.Revisions.AcceptAll
    rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink ' Replace 'wdPink' with the appropriate 
    color index
Next rev
End Sub
```

It worked in most documents but in a larger document (18 pages) I get:

> Run-time error '5852': Requested object is not available.

When I click 'Debug', it highlights the line: `Set rng = rev.Range`

This was posted in another forum:

```vb
Sub AcceptChangesAlt()
Dim tempState As Boolean
tempState = ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions

ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
Dim index As Long
Dim changeRange As Range

For index = ActiveDocument.Revisions.count To 1 Step -1
    Set changeRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    changeRange.Start = ActiveDocument.Revisions(index).Range.Start
    changeRange.End = ActiveDocument.Revisions(index).Range.End

    changeRange.Revisions.AcceptAll
    changeRange.Font.Color = 12611584 ' Set font color (change as needed)
Next

ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = tempState
End Sub
```

I get the same error. It highlights:

```
changeRange.Start = ActiveDocument.Revisions(index).Range.Start
```

I tried this:

```vb
Sub accept_changes()
tempState = ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions

ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
Dim index As Long, Change As Range
For index = ActiveDocument.Revisions.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set Change = ActiveDocument.Revisions(index).Range
    Change.Revisions.AcceptAll
    Change.Font.Color = 12611584
Next

ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = tempState
End Sub
```

I get the same error. It highlights:

```
Set Change = ActiveDocument.Revisions(index).Range
```

I've heard about a plugin called Zotero that can cause this error with macros. I don't have that plugin.

Comment: Try using `rev.Accept`, instead of `range.Acceptall`.  The first only accepts the revision you're currently handling, and not any other revisions which happen to overlap it (and which are supposed to be handled later).

Comment: If you still have this problem, you may want to look at this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76755737/11318818

Answer (score 0):

Word can act a little weird when it comes to accessing items in a `Collection` (which is the `.Revisions` object). So when you have

```vb
For Each rev In ActiveDocument.Revisions
    Set rng = rev.Range
    rng.Revisions.AcceptAll
    rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink ' Replace 'wdPink' with the appropriate color index
Next rev
```

To prevent the error condition when `rev` doesn't actually exist (even though it's in the collection), you must protect your code with a check:

```vb
For Each rev In ActiveDocument.Revisions
    If Not (rev Is Nothing) Then
        If Not (rev.Range Is Nothing) Then
            Set rng = rev.Range
            rng.Revisions.AcceptAll
            rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink ' Replace 'wdPink' with the appropriate color index
        End If
    End If
Next rev
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Peter. Unfortunately it still gives me the same 5852 error and the debugger highlights the 'Set rng = rev.Range' again!

Comment: @greenwood45 try the updated code in the answer above. The code also checks that the `.Range` property of the `rev` object exists before using it.

Comment: same issue, now it highlights  `If Not (rev.Range Is Nothing) Then`. Oh jeez.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error in my own Word document. However, I suspect that your problem is because you are not handling the different types of revisions. For example, your code will "highlight in pink" a range of words that was deleted (which makes no sense). You'll probably have to set up an `If (this type of revision) Then ... Else If (another type of revision) ...`. See [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.revision.type) and [this list of enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrevisiontype).